# App rejected because of external-accessory value in the UIBackgroundModes key

Tags: swift, xcode, app-store-connect

I accidentally turn on External accessory option in background modes and send the build to app store connect and after that, I receive the message which I show in image below,
after I uncheck the option (image attached) and send new build, and again I received the same message, what can I do now?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, verify that you've actually sent the build you meant to. You probably have, but it's easy sometimes to not build what you think you built. Go to Window>Organizer, find the archive that you sent, Show in Finder, Show Package Contents, and check the Info.plist.

If everything looks fine, click the "Submit an appeal" link that Apple gives you to explain the issue. That's why there's a link.